# XSLT Error: A semi colon character was expected

Tags: xml, url, xslt, hyperlink

I've got this url that I need to place in a link in some XSL. Not sure where the problem is. If I pull the link out of the XSL it works fine.

```
<a href="https://xxxxx.com/sites/mcpharm/ApplicantDocuments/Forms/ApplicantUpload.aspx?List=%7B3D4B5CEF%AF61%2DBFA1945747EA%7D&RootFolder=%2Fsites%2Fmcpharm%2FApplicantDocuments%2F{$QSApplicantID}&Source=https://xxxxx.com/sites/mcpharm/Lists/Applicant/Detail.aspx?ID={$QSApplicantID}">Upload New Document</a>
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Did you remember to encode any `&` characters as `&amp;`?

Answer (score 4):

XML attribute values *must* be XML-escaped. All instances of `&` in a URL for example must be written as `&amp;`.

The same is true for HTML, by the way, only that browsers (i.e. HTML parsers) are more forgiving than XML parsers.